# OrderBy and OrderByDescending are stable?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, sql-order-by

I am currently reading Pro LINQ c# 2008, and in page 87 the guy says OrderBy and OrderByDescending are stable. But he says exactly the opposite in page 96. It looks to me as he is referring to exactly the same functions, so I don't get it. Are they [stable or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important)?

Comment: I would assume without being stable, it would be impossible to implement `ThenBy`..

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, they're definitely stable. I picked up the same error in [my review](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/09/22/book-review-pro-linq-language-integrated-query-in-c-2008-by-joe-rattz.aspx) of the book.

Joe responded to that bit of my review with this:

> Just for your reader's knowledge, the
>   ordering is now specified to be
>   stable. Initially it was unstable, and
>   was later changed to be stable but I
>   was told it would be specified to be
>   unstable, but apparently at some
>   point, the specification was changed
>   to be stable. My book was updated but
>   apparently I missed a spot.

So yes, it was a mistake.

Overall it's a reasonably accurate book. (There are a few inaccuracies which are due to MSDN being inaccurate, but that's fairly easy to forgive.) There are *far* worse around :)

Comment: Ah, so funny. Now that I stalked your website I saw you wrote c# in depth, which I am reading too :P

Comment: If you find any similar mistakes in that, please do let me know :) Unfortunately the errata page on the web site isn't working at the moment, so you can't check whether I already know...

Comment: Will there ever be a More C# In Depth? :)

Comment: The review link you have mentioned doesn't work anymore. It says, *page not found*. Can you update that.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-3.5) page for Framework 3.5 (first release of `OrderBy`) says it was stable. Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 14):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), `OrderBy` is stable, as is [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx).