# What is the importance of "same ordering" objects being equal?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I'm sorting an array of objects. The objects have lots of fields but I only care about one of them. So, I wrote a comparator:

```
    Collections.sort(details, new Comparator<MyObj>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObj d1, MyObj d2) {
            if (d1.getDate() == null && d2.getDate() == null) {
                return 0;
            } else if (d1.getDate() == null) {
                return -1;
            } else if (d2.getDate() == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (d1.getDate().before(d2.getDate())) return 1;
            else if (d1.getDate().after(d2.getDate())) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }
    });
```

From the perspective of my use case, this `Comparator` does all it needs to, even if I might consider this sorting non-deterministic. However, I wonder if this is bad code. Through this `Comparator`, two very distinct objects could be considered "the same" ordering even if they are unequal objects. I decided to use `hashCode` as a tiebreaker, and it came out something like this:

```
    Collections.sort(details, new Comparator<MyObj>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MyObj d1, MyObj d2) {

            if (d1.getDate() == null && d2.getDate() == null) {
                return d1.hashCode();
            } else if (d1.getDate() == null) {
                return -1;
            } else if (d2.getDate() == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (d1.getDate().before(d2.getDate())) return 1;
            else if (d1.getDate().after(d2.getDate())) return -1;
            else return d1.hashCode() - d2.hashCode();
        }
    });
```

(what I return might be backwards, but that's is not important to this question)

Is this necessary?

**EDIT:**
To anyone else looking at this question, consider using Google's ordering API. The logic above was replaced by:

```
 return Ordering.<Date> natural().reverse().nullsLast().compare(d1.getDate(), d2.getDate());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Through this comparator, two very distinct objects could be considered "the same" ordering even if they are unequal objects.

That really doesn't matter; it's perfectly fine for two objects to *compare* as equal even if they are not "equal" in any other sense.  `Collections.sort` is a *stable* sort, meaning objects that compare as equal come out in the same order they came in; that's equivalent to just using "the index in the input" as a tiebreaker.

(Also, your new `Comparator` is actually significantly more broken than the original.  `return d1.hashCode()` is particularly nonsensical, and `return d1.hashCode() - d2.hashCode()` can lead to nontransitive orderings that will break `Collections.sort`, because of overflow issues.  Unless both integers are definitely nonnegative, which hashCodes aren't, always use `Integer.compare` to compare integers.)

Answer (score 2):

### This is only mostly important if the objects [`implement Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. **This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals.** In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.
>
> For example, if one adds two keys a and b such that (`!a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) == 0`) to a sorted set that does not use an explicit comparator, the second add operation returns false (and the size of the sorted set does not increase) because a and b are equivalent from the sorted set's perspective.

However, you're not doing that, you're using a custom `Comparator`, probably for presentation reasons. Since this sorting metric isn't inherently attached to the object, it doesn't matter that much.

---

As an aside, why not just return 0 instead of messing with the hashCodes? Then they will preserve the *original order* if the dates match, because `Collections.sort` is a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517793/1768232). I agree with [@LouisWasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32257384/1768232) that using hashCode in this way can have potentially very bizarre consequences, mostly relating to integer overflow.  Consider the case where `d1.hashCode()` is positive and `d2.hashCode()` is negative, and vice versa.