# How to sort all combinations in python?

Tags: python, combinations

I have `K=2` and `N=3` and I generate all combinations as follows:

```
list(itertools.product(range(1, N+1), repeat=K))
```

and I get

```
[(1, 1), 
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3), 
 (2, 1), 
 (2, 2), 
 (2, 3), 
 (3, 1), 
 (3, 2), 
 (3, 3)]
```

I need to sort these combinations to get

```
[(1, 1), 
 (2, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3), 
 (2, 1), 
 (2, 3), 
 (3, 1), 
 (3, 2)]
```

How can I do this for general `K` and `N`?

It is like having `N` bins and `K` items and I would like to produce all possible assignment of items to bins but starting with

- all items assigned to bin 1, then bin 2, etc.
- K-1 items assigned to bin 1, and one item to bin 2, etc.
- ...

So in the example `(1, 1)` means that all items are in bin 1, `(2, 2)` means that all items are in bin 2, etc. `(1, 2)` means that item 1 is in bin 1 and item 2 is in bin 2, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already generated *almost* how you wanted, so you can take advantage of python's sort being stable:

```
>>> L = list(itertools.product(range(1, N+1), repeat=K))
>>> L.sort(key=lambda t: len(set(t)))
>>> L
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

This just pushes the tuples with the most equal values towards the front.  It should generalise to higher dimensions consistent with the way you've described.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. len(set(t)) would always return 2, no? Would you be able to explain what's going on and what you mean by the sort being 'stable' means?

Comment: @freebie As for the lambda function, `len(set(t))` will return 1 for `set((1,1))`, 2 for `set((1,2))`, etc. This is because in sets we do not have the same element more than once (unless it is a multiset). So, in fact, `set((1,1))={1}` in  python.

Comment: @Riebuoz ah yeah, I see. so the sort being 'stable' means that if elements are equivalent they will remain in their original location? Would it be much more complex to solve it otherwise?

Comment: Yes. You can see the explanation here also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1517824/3745674. I do not know about the complexity but I think that, in the worst case, it does not matter.

Comment: Ah, so from that post it says the benefit is stacking for sorts. So if they started out unordered (`random.shuffle`) you could `L.sort()` then `L.sort(key=lambda t: len(set(t)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
import itertools
K = 2
N = 3
a = list(itertools.product(range(1, N+1), repeat=K))
a_sorted = sorted(a, key=lambda t: -(t[0] == t[1]))
```

The `lambda` function tells `sorted` to place the tuples with equal numbers in the beginning. We also need to sort after the numeric value, but as this is the default behavior of `sorted`, we do not need to add this in by hand.

Comment: Right. Your `lambda t: len(set(t))` is better.

Comment: Why `-(t[0] == t[1])` rather than `t[0] != t[1]`?

Comment: Indeed `t[0] != t[1]` is nicer. When I came up with the answer I thought in terms of numerical factors and not in simple booleans.