# Sort null values to last in Array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}]
```

I want to kind-of sort them by the objects having values first then objects with null.

What I tried is:

```
c.sort(function(b) { return b.a ? -1 : 1 })
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[{a: 2}, {a: 50}, {a: 1}, {a: 12}, {a: null}, {a: null}]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
[{a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}, {a: null}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @GokulanPH Yes, I can. I just haven't used it in my question, so didn't tag it

Comment: The [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function has an arity of 2, it has an `a` and `b` argument for comparison.

Comment: Also, beware of sort stability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/stability-in-sorting-algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test the value. If `null`, then take the delta of the comparison.

```js
var c = [{ a: null }, { a: 12 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 50 }, { a: 2 }, { a: null }];

c.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.a === null) - (b.a === null);
});

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a stable sort, you could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and use the indices as second sort option.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var list = [{ a: null }, { a: 12 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 50 }, { a: 2 }, { a: null }];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list.map(function(el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.a === null};
});

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value || a.index - b.index;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function(el){
    return list[el.index];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome solution

Answer (score 7):

This will put nulls and other falsy values to the end of the list:

```js
c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}];
c.sort((x, y) => !!y.a - !!x.a);

console.log(c);
```

However, since you don't really sort anything, you can just split the list into two parts an rejoin them:

```js
c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}];

r = [
  ...c.filter(x => x.a !== null),
  ...c.filter(x => x.a === null)
]

console.log(r)
```

This also doesn't rely on the `sort` function being stable.

Comment: it moves zero values to the bottom.

Comment: The `filter` option is much better than using `sort` in this use case, it avoids any stability problems.

Answer (score 1):

That way ?

```
c=[{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}];
c.sort(function(a,b){ return a.a===null ? 1:-1 })
console.log(c);
```

Edited

Comment: This sorts the objects, I just want to push objects with null values to last

Answer (score 1):

```js
const c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}];

let result = [...c.filter(_=>_["a"]!==null),...c.filter(_=>_["a"]===null)];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var c = [{
  a: null
}, {
  a: 12
}, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 50
}, {
  a: 2
}, {
  a: null
}];

c.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a.a !== null) ? 0 : 1;
});
console.log(c);
```

Returning `0` in the sort function will keep the order as it is.

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Although  @Xotic750's comment **"The Array#sort function has an arity of 2, it has an a and b argument for comparison."** is right, but this answer worked for me.

Comment: maybe i see wrong, but in edge, i see a null value at top and one at bottom. it heavily rely on just one side of the compairing between two vaules.

Comment: @vsr, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `return !a.a - !b.a` .valid object  goes first

```js
var c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}];

c.sort(function (a, b) {
    return !a.a - !b.a
});
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but still works,cheers!

```js
var c = [{a: null}, {a: 12}, {a: 1}, {a: 50}, {a: 2}, {a: null}]

c.sort(function(object1,object2){

  
  if(object1.a === null && object2.a !== null){return 1}
  
  if([object1.a,object2.a].every((a)=>a === null) ||      
     [object1.a,object2.a].every((a)=>a !== null)
     ){return 0}
  
  if(object1.a !== null && object2.a === null){return -1}
  


})

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a case of sorting a Date with null value at the end if exists:

```
userSortList = users.sort((a, b) => {
    if (b.lastConnectionDate === null || a.lastConnectionDate) {
        return -1
    } else {
        return (
            new Date(b.lastConnectionDate) - new Date(a.lastConnectionDate)
        )
    }
})
```