# Oracle query row order is different when using between with ROW_NUM

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Between condition in ORACLE, to achieve pagination. I will sort data on CNT column in descending order to display most counted value first.

I am getting different row order with normal order by and row number order by.

Below is my data set:

```
PATTERN_TBL

PATTERN  |  CNT
1        |  3
Aaaa Aaa |  14
aaaaaa   |  3
```

Normal Query:

```
SELECT PATTERN, CNT FROM PATTERN_TBL ORDER BY CNT DESC

PATTERN  |  CNT
Aaaa Aaa |  14
aaaaaa   |  3
1        |  3
```

Between Query:

```
SELECT ROW_N, PATTERN,CNT FROM (SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CNT DESC) AS ROW_N,
  PATTERN, CNT FROM PATTERN_TBL) 
WHERE ROW_N BETWEEN 1 AND 100 

PATTERN  |  CNT
Aaaa Aaa |  14
1        |  3
aaaaaa   |  3
```

In the above two outputs, row #3 and row #2 are interchanging. I want to fix order. How can i do that?

Comment: The second query has no `order by`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have two rows with the same value for `cnt`.  This brings up the larger issue of *stable sorts*.

Sorting in relational databases is not stable (the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important) gives a good description of stable sorts).  That is, when the `order by` keys have the same value they can appear in any order.  They can appear in different orders on different runs.

This is actually obvious.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  That is, there is no natural ordering, so there is no way to define a stable sort.

If you want consistency in sorts, you need to be sure that the keys uniquely define each row.  I usually have an id column that can be added as the last key to the `order by`.

In your case, you may be able to use the pattern:  `order by cnt desc, pattern`.

Comment: Gordon, As per my requirement I cant combine another column in sorting. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Nivedikathakur . . . Nope.  That is how sorting works in SQL.  Why can't you add another column?  SQL certainly allows it.

Comment: I need to show most repeated values(cnt column) on the top. If i add another column it will disturbs the row order.

Comment: @Nivedikathakur . . . The largest count value will always be in the first row returned -- whether or not you add an extra key.  I have no idea what you mean by "disturbs the row order".  The whole point is that you seem to want a stable sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY CNT DESC, PATTERN
```

would work in your case.

If not, a possibility might be to use the [pseudocolumn ORA_ROWSCN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm)

```
ORDER BY CNT DESC, ORA_ROWSCN
```

This would work if the records you retrieve were not batch-inserted at the same time. Not sure if you can use it in a window function though, try it