# Do equal elements preserve their order in Insertion Sort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

In the "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" book of Robert Lafore it is stated that the Insertion Sort is a stable algorithm. Which means that equal items preserve their order.

Here is the example from the book:

```
public void insertionSort() {
    int in, out;
    for (out = 1; out < nElems; out++) // out is dividing line
    {
        long temp = a[out]; // remove marked item
        in = out; // start shifts at out
        while (in > 0 && a[in - 1] >= temp) // until one is smaller,
        {
            a[in] = a[in - 1]; // shift item right,
            --in; // go left one position
        }
        a[in] = temp; // insert marked item
    } // end for
} // end insertionSort()
```

In the `while` cycle we are going left and seeking for a place for `temp` variable. And even if `a[in - 1] == temp`, we still move one step left and insert `tmp` before `a[in - 1]` while in the original array `tmp` was to the right of `a[in - 1]`.

The order of array elements changed after the sorting. How is this algorithm is stable then? Shouldn't there just be `a[in - 1] > temp` instead of `a[in - 1] >= temp`?

Maybe i'm just making a mistake and don't see something obvious?

Comment: "ordered items preserve their order" goes for all (correct) sort algorithms, by definition. A "stable" sort means equal items preserve their order.

Comment: Any sort is going to change the unequal items. What makes a sort stable is that it keeps equal items in the same relative order they were beforehand. (For example, sorting on a different column in a table will keep the rows within each category subsorted.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important

Comment: Yes, you are right, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: From what I can see with mental debugging the algorithm is not stable and hence wrong, it should be `> temp`. You should verify it with real debugging.

Comment: Tried debugging, ">=" changes the order whereas ">" seem to be working fine. There seem to be an error in the examle, I couldn't believe.

Comment: It happens ... . Sometimes the publisher or the author post fixes online. Check if it happened in this case and if not consider sending them an email.

Comment: You can do it [here](http://www.informit.com/store/data-structures-and-algorithms-in-java-9780672324536) it's possible you're the first one to notice.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks! Just posted link to this page :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely right. This here is a snippet of the Insertion Sort Algorithm from the popular book "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H. Cormen.

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1. for j=2 to A.length
2. key = A[j]
3. // Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1..j-1].
4. i = j-1
5. while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6. A[i+1] = A[i]
7. i = i-1
8. A[i+1] = key
```

As you can see, A[i] > key is correct. It should be "a[in - 1] > temp" in your case.
Good job at noticing it. :)