# Why does R use radix sort?

Tags: r, data.table, radix-sort

From my understanding, R's `order()` method uses radix sort by default.  This was not always the case (see [news](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.pdf)), but Matt Dowle made [this presentation](http://user2015.math.aau.dk/presentations/234.pdf) suggesting change because radix sort empirically performs well.

My question is, why is radix sort better than other sorting algorithms in practice? [Wikipedia doesn't make a strong case for radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency). Also, why do other popular languages/tools like Python and pandas not use radix sort by default, if it is truly the *best* sorting algorithm?

Comment: I really don't get it why this question has been downvoted.  Of course there is room for improvement in its formulation, but its core is not shallow.

Answer (score 3):

As you know, there is not any *best* sorting algorithm in general case.
A solution can be **Radix sort is a stable sort**. Hence, as in R keeping the order of tie cases could be important, they implemented a stable sort method.

You can find more about the stability [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) and also in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517793/3768871).

Another point is, as stability can be important in different situations, you should find the best between stable sort algorithms which come [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts).

**B**

- Block sort
- Bubble sort
- Bucket sort

**C**

- Cascade merge sort
- Cocktail shaker sort
- Counting sort
- Cubesort

**G**

- Gnome sort

**I**

- Insertion sort

**L**

- Library sort

**M**

- Merge sort

**O**

- Odd–even sort
- Oscillating merge sort

**P**

- Pigeonhole sort
- Proxmap sort

**R**

- Radix sort

**T**

- Timsort