# Does stable_sort() also preserve the order of unequal elements?

Tags: c++

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), I know that for `stable_sort`:

> The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved.

I also read this question [What is stability in sorting algorithms and why is it important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important) and understand the concept and basic usage of *stability*.

Here's how I understand stable sort:
Let's say I have unordered flight *departure time* and *destination*.

First, I sort it by time. It would be like

```
d-time dest
   1     A
   2     B
   3     C
   4     A
   5     B
```

Then stable sort by dest. It would be like

```
 dest   d-time
   A     1   (stable sort guarantee that [A,1] comes before [A,4])
   A     4
   B     2   (stable sort guarantee that [B,2] comes before [B,5])
   B     5
   C     3
```

---

But an example *C++ Primer* seems to indicate that `stable_sort` also guarantee the order of previous **unequal elements** (if so, it means `stable_sort` keeps all the original order).

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> words;
    string in_word;
    istringstream isin("the quick red fox jumps over slow turtles");
    while (isin >> in_word) {
        words.push_back(in_word);
    }
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end());
    words.erase(end_unique, words.end());

    stable_sort(words.begin(), words.end(), isShorter);

    for (auto &s : words) {
        cout << s << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here's the text makes me question that whether `stable_sort` keeps all the original elements' order.

> Assuming `words` was in alphabetical order before this call (the first sorting and erasing function calls), after the call, `words` will be sorted by element size, and **the words of each length remain in alphabetical order.** If we run this code on our original vector, the output will be
>   `fox red the over slow jumps quick turtle`

After first sorting and erasing, I have:
`fox jumps over quick red slow the turtles`

After stable sort, I have:
`fox red the over slow jumps quick turtle`

---

So my question is:

For `stable_sort`, just see the first 3 elements:

`fox red the`, is this order fixed? Or it's just one possible order among the arrangements:

`fox red the`
`fox the red`
`the red fox`
`the fox red`
... (6 results)

I mean, the document **only** said `stable_sort` keeps the original order of **equal elements**. `fox red the` are not equal. They have order. But from the quoted text and output, it seems to indicate that *It simply keeps all the original order*.

Do I misunderstand something or the textbook is wrong here and the output is just happened to follow the previous sorting order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fox`, `red`, and `the` are equal for the purposes of the `stable_sort`. The cppreference link you have says:

> Elements are compared using the given comparison function comp.

So, yes the `fox red the` order is fixed for your example, as the stable_sort won't change the relative order of those three (equally short) items.

Comment: OMG, I think I get it wrong before. So it's *The order of equal elements(in stable sort) is guaranteed to be preserved.* but not what I used to understand that *The order of equal elements(in previsous order) is guaranteed to be preserved (in stable sort).*

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be more precise to say that the order of *equivalent* elements is guaranteed to be preserved.  Or even more exactly, `stable_sort` preserves the order of elements that are equivalent with respect to the ordering comparison used for the sort.

Like many standard algorithms, `std::stable_sort` requires the comparison method to be used to be a Strict Weak Ordering on the elements in the range.  This is true both for the versions that use `operator<` and for the versions that use a passed `Compare` object.  Part of the definition of a Strict Weak Ordering is that the binary relation determined by `!(x<y || y<x)` or `!(comp(x,y) || comp(y,x))` is an Equivalence Relation.

So in your first example, two of your elements are `[A,1]` and `[A,4]`.  In the context of the stable sort by destination, presumably your comparison functor would return false for both `comp([A,1], [A,4])` and `comp([A,4], [A,1])`, so the elements are equivalent.  But we can say they are not equal, in the sense that they are not identical.  (Note this is all entirely independent of the meaning of any `operator==` or `operator!=` function for the element type, if such a thing is even defined at all.)

In the word sorting example, `"fox"` and `"red"` are equivalent with respect to `isShorter`, because `isShorter("fox", "red")` and `isShorter("red", "fox")` are both false.  So the `stable_sort` call using `isShorter` must preserve the fact that `"fox"` comes before `"red"`.  But again, these two words are clearly not identical.  And yes, the order `fox red the` is fixed, because the sort must preserve the relative ordering of all these words from the same equivalence class.  On the other hand, `"red"` and `"jumps"` are not equivalent, since `isShorter("red", "jumps")` is true, so the sort needs to swap orderings so that `"red"` ends up somewhere earlier than `"jumps"`.

In fact, for any range and valid Strict Weak Ordering comparison, there is only one allowed result of `std::stable_sort` (unlike `std::sort`, which would be correct given any reordering of each equivalence class of elements in the sequence).

Comment: Yes. I think I misunderstood the documentation. I mean, I used to think that *The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved.* means: if the elements in previous order are considered equal, then in the coming stable sort, they would follow the previous order. But the correct understanding is: if the elements in stable sort are considered equal, then they would follow the previous order.

Comment: Right. It's not even necessarily the case that there was a previous sort at all. Maybe the order some data was originally input is important, so you just read it in, then use a `stable_sort` because you still want to know which of equivalent inputs were entered earlier. The order being preserved is simply the order within the sequence at the moment the stable sort starts.

Comment: Thank you very much. 。(O^~^O)