# Sort file by only first two columns and keep the input order in case the columns have same values

Tags: bash, sorting, columnsorting, stability

I have an input file which lines I'd like sort by only 2 first columns. And I'd like to know if there is some way to do it with sort command in bash.

Ex. Input File:

> `cat checkstart.txt`
>
> ```
> dev XCUBOBS149 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> dev XCUBOBS150 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> dev XCUBOBS149 NO_LINKS_TO_STARTSCRIPTS
> dev XCUBOBS149 ufabric:x:46000:46000::/home/ufabric:/bin/bash
> dev XCUBOBS149 export JAVA_HOME=/soft/jdk/jdk1.7.0_79/
> ```

I'm trying with

> `sort -b -k1,2 checkstart.txt`

but result is not what I'm expecting because it's sorting all the lines by alphanumerical order:

> ```
> dev XCUBOBS149 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> dev XCUBOBS149 export JAVA_HOME=/soft/jdk/jdk1.7.0_79/
> dev XCUBOBS149 NO_LINKS_TO_STARTSCRIPTS
> dev XCUBOBS149 ufabric:x:46000:46000::/home/ufabric:/bin/bash
> dev XCUBOBS150 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> ```

I'd like get a result file like this:

> ```
> dev XCUBOBS149 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> dev XCUBOBS149 NO_LINKS_TO_STARTSCRIPTS
> dev XCUBOBS149 ufabric:x:46000:46000::/home/ufabric:/bin/bash
> dev XCUBOBS149 export JAVA_HOME=/soft/jdk/jdk1.7.0_79/
> dev XCUBOBS150 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a [*stable*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517793/6862601) sort algorithm. `sort` provides one. You can enable it with the `-s` option.

```
$ sort -s -k1,2 checkstart.txt
dev XCUBOBS149 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
dev XCUBOBS149 NO_LINKS_TO_STARTSCRIPTS
dev XCUBOBS149 ufabric:x:46000:46000::/home/ufabric:/bin/bash
dev XCUBOBS149 export JAVA_HOME=/soft/jdk/jdk1.7.0_79/
dev XCUBOBS150 /etc/init.d/DSEngine_srv
```

Comment: thank you so much @Socowi, it's just I was looking for!