# Algorithm for Validation of Reference File with Wildcards

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a file like below, which I want to validate for correctness. The file is used as a reference file for processing some data. I match my input data with ColA, ColB and ColC of this file and return OutA of the first match from top. The wildcards '*' match anything. For example, if my input data has `X4 Y2 Z3` it will return 13 from the file.

```
Seq  ColA  ColB  ColC  OutA
1    X1    Y1    Z1    10
2    X2    Y2    *     11
3    X3    *     Z2    12
4    *     Y2    Z3    13
5    *     *     Z4    14
6    *     Y3    Z4    15
7    *     *     *     16
```

Now the file can have some entries that are never used or reachable. For example, if I receive `X9 Y3 Z4` as my input, it will match with row 5, and will never look at row 6 although row 6 also matches my input. If we exchange the position of row 5 and row 6, it will work as expected. I want to find such unreachable records before my actual process runs.

Any idea on how to find such entries in the file. I am looking for an algorithm. Note that, I have reduced the number of columns and rows in this example. The actual file has around 10 columns and 50 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that wildcards match every string (specifically, for each column, there exists a valid symbol that does not appear as a literal), it suffices to check each pair of rows to see whether the first matches a superset of what the second matches. This is the case if and only if, for each column, if the second row has a literal, and then first row has the same literal or a wildcard, and if the second row has a wildcard, then the first row has a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks David. So for my 50 row file, I have to do  (49+48+...+3+2+1) row compares, which isn't bad. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the approach most web servers use to match request urls to controllers. They take exactly that controller, which fits the resource url best.

```
/users
/users/{userId}
```

If you see a request like `/users/2` you would, of course, prefer the second resource controller.

Now back to your problem, the varibale part (you want to match best) relates to the use of `*`. If you want to achieve a best-fit, you have to sort all entries, those with the lowest amount of `*` at the top, those with the highest at the bottom. (Since you iterate from top to bottom and return upon first match.)

However, for all entries that have the same amount of `*`, there can be mutliple fitting rows and there is *no* way to prevent that. You have to decide, which is one taken.

An simple example demonstrates this:

```
Seq  ColA  ColB  ColC  OutA
20   X3    *     Z3    12
21   *     Y2    Z3    13
```

What do you do with `X3, Y2, Z3`? The output is not clear and will depend on the sort order. My adwise: Use a [stable sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important) to make the output predictable.

For implementation, just create a custom comparator that counts the amount of `*` used.

A quick look at `List#sort` also shows, that a stable sorting algorithm is already used so you don´t have to worry about it. ([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-))

> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort [...]

Comment: Thanks Glains. Stable sort looks promising. But since the file is maintained by our end users, I would rather alert them on the wrong sort order instead of sorting it myself. I guess what I was asking can be accomplished by simply counting the number of `*` and find out at which row it decreased.

Comment: On second thought, that is not going to work. if I have two entries like this `X4    *    */X5    Y5    * `. They are perfectly valid.