# How to create a conditional sorting in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let us say I have a list of points returned with a sort function:

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(); 
points.add(new Point(3, 30)); 
points.add(new Point(1, 10)); 
points.add(new Point(2, 20));

points.stream() 
.sorted((p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x)) 
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

How do I make sorted(...) conditional based on a boolean flag (`sortThePoints`), something like the below

```
points.stream()
if(sortThePoints){
 .sorted((p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x)) 
}
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `if(sortThePoints) Collections.sort(points, (p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x))`

Comment: Is `sortThePoints` affects the collection elements?? If yes then use `filter()`;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Stream.sorted(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) makes a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important) if the stream is ordered. In other words, if two elements are equals then they'll keep their initial ordering.

```
static final Comparator<Point> identityComparator = (p1, p2) -> 0;

Comparator<Point> normalComparator = (p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x);

(or Comparator<Point> normalComparator = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.x))

points.stream()
.sorted(sortThePoints ? normalComparator : identityComparator)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: In your solution ech element passes the sorting/comparator, regardless if sorting is enabled or not. Readability also is misleading a bit, since `sorted()` step is in place anyway (even if conditional identity-comparator could be without effect).

Answer (score 5):

You can break the chain, using a variable:

```
Stream<Point> pointStream = points.stream();

if(sortThePoints) {
    pointsStream = pointsStream.sorted((p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x));
}

pointsStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just store the stream into a variable and then keep reassigning based on logic

```
Stream<Point> points = Stream.of(new Point(3, 30, new Point(1, 10), new Point(2, 20)));

if (sortValues)
    points = points.sorted((p1, p2)->p1.x.compareTo(p2.x));

points.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This solution expresses __very clear__, if sorting is performed or not. To have the condition check outside the stream __avoids unnecessary processing__. Thus its clean and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need this.

```java
class enum SortType {
    X, Y, REVERSE_X, REVERSE_Y
};


List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(); 
points.add(new Point(3, 30)); 
points.add(new Point(1, 10)); 
points.add(new Point(2, 20));

Comparator<Point> comparatorX = (Point p1, Point p2) -> p1.getX().compareTo(p2.getX()); 
Comparator<Point> comparatorY = (Point p1, Point p2) -> p1.getY().compareTo(p2.getY()); 

SortType sortType = SortType.X
swich(sortType) {
    case X:
        Collections.sort(points, comparatorX); 
        break;
    case REVERSE_X:
        Collections.sort(points, comparatorX.reversed()); 
        break;
    case Y:
        Collections.sort(points, comparatorY); 
        break;
    case REVERSE_Y:
        Collections.sort(points, comparatorY.reversed()); 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```