# Handle null with localecompare typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following sort:

```
let sortedCon = this.con.sort((a, b) => a.lastname.localeCompare(b.lastname));
```

I am trying to get it to handle nulls and maintain the one line simplicity.

I have tried this but not working:

```
let sortedCon = this.con.sort((a, b) => a ? a.lastname.localeCompare(b ? b.lastname : '') : 0);
```

I know I am close but cant figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of `this.con`?  A [mcve] is helpful to give you the best answer.  And what version of TypeScript are you using? TypeScript 3.7 introduced the [optional chaining](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) and [nullish coalescing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operators which will help shorten this code.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a minimum reproducible example including the type definitions for `this.con` as well as the particular sort order you'd like to see (if an element of `this.con` is not defined, should it sort in the same place as if it were defined with an empty `lastname`?  or somewhere else?), it's hard to be sure, but assuming it's something like:

```
declare const con: Array<{
    lastname?: string | null
} | null | undefined>;
```

then you can use the [optional chaining](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) and [nullish coalescing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operators introduced in TypeScript 3.7 to get the following one-liner:

```
con.sort((a, b) => (a?.lastname ?? "").localeCompare(b?.lastname ?? ""));
```

The optional chaining in `a?.lastname` is similar to `(a != null ? a.lastname : undefined)`, and the nullish coalescing `expr ?? ""` is similar to `(expr != null ? expr : "")`.  So that together produces something similar to

```
con.sort((a, b) => ((a || {}).lastname || "").localeCompare((b || {}).lastname || ""));
```

which is uglier but should work in TS3.6 and below.  Both of these make the elements `null`, `{lastname: undefined}`, `{lastname: null}`, and `{lastname: ""}` all interchangeable in terms of the sort order.  If you want to see those sorted in some particular order with respect to each other or with respect to elements with non-empty `lastname` properties, then you should specify that in the question.

---

Let's see how it acts:

```
const con: Array<{ lastname?: string | null } | null | undefined> = [
    { lastname: "" },
    { lastname: "B" },
    { lastname: null },
    null,
    { lastname: "A" },
    {},
    { lastname: "C" }
]    
console.log(JSON.stringify(con));
// [{"lastname":""},{"lastname":"B"},{"lastname":null},null,{"lastname":"A"},{},{"lastname":"C"}]
```

Sorting with the TS3.7 code:

```
const newCon = con.slice();
newCon.sort((a, b) => (a?.lastname ?? "").localeCompare(b?.lastname ?? ""));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newCon));
// [{"lastname":""},{"lastname":null},null,{},{"lastname":"A"},{"lastname":"B"},{"lastname":"C"}]
```

and with the TS3.6- code:

```
const newCon2 = con.slice();
newCon2.sort((a, b) => ((a || {}).lastname || "").localeCompare((b || {}).lastname || ""));
console.log(JSON.stringify(newCon2));
// [{"lastname":""},{"lastname":null},null,{},{"lastname":"A"},{"lastname":"B"},{"lastname":"C"}]
```

both yields the same ordering, where the "empty" elements are moved to the front and in the original order from the array (you can't *count* on [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) being [stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important) but it usually is), and the rest of the elements are sorted in order of the `lastname` property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYC4YEEBOqCGBPAPAbxgBsNowMBbAUwH4lpUBLMAcxgB8YwBXQwmAX3acefDlzAATSgDMmlCQD4YAXhgBtAFAxtMAsVIVKSAETGBAGi069JKGSomAQmf6WduorftHhvC1e1uXjdrTwMHGGNkFxDtPFcAj307QxMAYRcNAF0tDQ14CBBCSgA6QhBmAAoAKQBlAHkAORL6JmYGaSxK+ABKHoBuDQB6IfU8Y2TvYwRTV3HJw2njZzmJr0WEIMJXLfN59aol6LnVhcOZjP4c-PBoTkoAdzTwFThwFsIGYEpKgY0wR7PMAtECoKCVSoYcwwABGPRUSkh1DKB0oMGo1Eixh6ZRAwAwxWe5AADhhUD8YcizmiMVi+oMCkVSuUqnUmi0oIwWB0ugCnuB6cNRmp9uFKEtjKdUdMtjsRHspWKjpK9mslTMVqrqUtLtcCrA+UCAEyveAfL4-P6G8BGkFgiFQ2Hw5SIyHsDjxHHU9103H4wkgElkn6VGE+z0osU+0yCxnFXGshrNVrczqVa1gI2CkZjNUpc6zLXSzYiOXBeJF9VRFWi-PijU1vNTC6S64aIA)

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: It looks like I have TS3.6 and below.  Worked perfect jcalz, very nice!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
let sortedCon = this.con.sort((a, b) => a && a.lastname && a.lastname.localeCompare(b && b.lastname : '') : 0);
```

Comment: what if `a.lastname` is null ? Also, i'm not sure all of this is valid syntax ( `(b && b.lastname : '') : 0`)

Comment: Thank you Matheus.  It is currently giving me a typescript error in the last two colons:   It says: ", expected".

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, you need to evaluate the lastname field, if the lastname is null change it to an empty string ---> ""

```
this.con.sort((a:any, b:any) => (a.lastName || "").localeCompare(b.lastName || "")
```