# Java: Understand how Comparator works (returning -1 and 0 )

Tags: java, compare, comparator, comparable

Here is the code

```java
class Solution {
    public String[] reorderLogFiles(String[] logs) {
        Arrays.sort(logs, (s1, s2) -> {
            String[] split1 = s1.split(" ", 2);
            String[] split2 = s2.split(" ", 2);

            boolean isDigit1 = Character.isDigit(split1[1].charAt(0));
            boolean isDigit2 = Character.isDigit(split2[1].charAt(0));

            if(!isDigit1 && !isDigit2) {
                // both letter-logs. 
                int comp = split1[1].compareTo(split2[1]);
                if (comp == 0) return split1[0].compareTo(split2[0]);
                else return comp;
            } else if (isDigit1 && isDigit2) {
                // both digit-logs. So keep them in original order
                return 0; 
            } else if (isDigit1 && !isDigit2) {
                // first is digit, second is letter. bring letter to forward.
                return 1;
            } else {
                //first is letter, second is digit. keep them in this order.
                return -1; 
            }
        });
        return logs;
    }
}
```

**This is the problem statement**

You have an array of logs.  Each log is a space delimited string of words.

For each log, the first word in each log is an alphanumeric identifier.  Then, either:

```
Each word after the identifier will consist only of lowercase letters, or;
Each word after the identifier will consist only of digits.
```

We will call these two varieties of logs letter-logs and digit-logs.  It is guaranteed that each log has at least one word after its identifier.

Reorder the logs so that all of the letter-logs come before any digit-log.  The letter-logs are ordered lexicographically ignoring identifier, with the identifier used in case of ties.  The digit-logs should be put in their original order.

Return the final order of the logs.

Example 1:

```
Input: logs = ["dig1 8 1 5 1","let1 art can","dig2 3 6","let2 own kit dig","let3 art zero"]
Output: ["let1 art can","let3 art zero","let2 own kit dig","dig1 8 1 5 1","dig2 3 6"]
```

**My Query**

What I don't understand is, the difference between returning 0 and returning -1

What I thought was -1 doesn't change the original order of two objects when compared, but returning 0 does the same thing. So, what's the actual difference? Thank you

Comment: 0 means the ordering is equal, -1 means the first argument comes before the second argument

Comment: but isn't the first argument already before the second argument?

Comment: zero doesn't necessarily "keep them in original order" btw. That depends entirely on the [stability of the sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important). You got lucky, the underlying algorithm is - I believe - timsort, which is stable. Technically that is an implementation detail which could change in future versions.

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Like I said, there is a difference between 0 and -1, between something being equal and something being less than. "*-1 doesn't change the original order of two objects when compared*" It does. It puts the first argument before the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Comparable<T>`'s `int compareTo(T o)` method compares `this` with the object specified, `Comparator<T>`'s `int compare(T o1, T o2)` compares two different instances of the same type. Both methods have a the same mathematical contract. As mentioned in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. Throws `ClassCastException` if the specified object’s type prevents it from being compared to this object.
>
> In the following description, the notation `sgn(expression)` designates the mathematical `signum` function, which is defined to return -1, 0, or 1, according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero, or positive.
>
> • The implementor must ensure that `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all x and y. (This implies that `x.compareTo(y)` must throw an exception if and only if `y.compareTo(x)` throws an exception.)
>
> • The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `(x.compareTo(y) > 0 && y.compareTo(z) > 0)` implies `x.compareTo(z) > 0`.
>
> • Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y) == 0` implies that
>   `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))`, for all z.
>
> • It is strongly recommended, but not required, that `(x.compareTo(y) == 0) == (x.equals(y))`. Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact.

Answer (score 0):

For `Comparator`'s, `Comparable`, etc..., there are two arguments passed. You return any negative number if the second argument is bigger, 0 if they are equal, and a positive number if the first argument is bigger. It doesn't have to be -1 or 1 for negative and positive numbers. For example, if you're comparing which number is larger, `compare(5, 10)` would return something negative, like -1, because 10 is larger than 5.

Comment: Comparable has only one argument.