# Why does adding two .OrderBy (or .OrderByDescending) statements apply the sorts in reverse order?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I came across the following in some code that I was refactoring today.

```
context.Entities.Where(x => x.ForeignKeyId == id)
    .OrderBy(x => x.FirstSortField)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SecondSortField);
```

Initially, I took out the `.OrderBy(x => x.FirstSortField)` thinking that the first OrderBy statement would just be replaced by the second OrderBy.  After testing, I realized that it was generating the SQL as `ORDER BY SecondSortField, FirstSortField`.

Therefore, the equivalent is actually:

```
context.Entities.Where(x => x.ForeignKeyId == id)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SecondSortField)
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstSortField);
```

Can anyone explain the reasoning behind EF6 doing this?  It seems to me that it would be more intuitive to replace the first sort field with the second.

Comment: The first `OrderBy` *is* replaced by the second. Your "equivalent" is not an equivalent.

Comment: @GertArnold, That's what I initially thought it would do, until I started testing.  If you try this in LinqPad, for example, the SQL it generates for these two statements is equivalent.

Comment: Of course that's what I did. EF6, EF core 3. Sql Server. Maybe another database provider is in play?

Comment: @GertArnold It's not a simple replacement if you're sorting data with lots of ties on the later field.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's not LINQ-to-objects. The query is very simply translated into one ORDER BY statement. Is see it happen right in front of me.

Comment: @WyattEarp Since you seem to actually see the generated `ORDER BY` as you show it, it makes me wonder what the defining factor is here. Are you in SQL server too? Is the actual query you based this upon different in some aspect that didn't seem important? Really, it's not that I don't believe you, it's this difference that fascinates me.

Comment: Please see my comment on user1344783's answer. Are you sure you're using EF as data provider?

Comment: @GertArnold, I am trying it in LinqPad 5 (EF 6) and LinqPad 6 (EF Core) and seeing the same behavior in both.  The database I'm testing against is SQL Server 2016. I also simplified the query that I'm using down to bare minimum.  I'm doing var d = `Dashboards.OrderBy(o => o.Name).OrderBy(o => o.DisplayName).ToList();`, where Dashboards is a table in the database.  The SQL generated is `SELECT [t0].[DashboardId], ... FROM [UI].[Dashboard] AS [t0] ORDER BY [t0].[DisplayName], [t0].[Name]`

Comment: `[t0]` is the LINQ-to-SQL prefix. EF generates other prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only conclude that we're actually looking at LINQ-to-SQL here. In Linqpad until v. 5, it's very easy to make this mistake, because the selection of a EF6 DbContext driver is easily overlooked when creating a new connection. (In Linqpad v6 this choice is more conspicuous).

I have tested the reported behavior in EF6, EF-core 3 and 5, and in LINQ-to-SQL. *Only* in the latter do I see a generated SQL statement with two columns in the `ORDER BY`.

The statement...

```cs
Products.OrderBy(p => p.Description).OrderBy(p => p.LastSale)
```

...is translated by LINQ-to-SQL as:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Discontinued], [t0].[LastSale]
FROM [Product] AS [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[LastSale], [t0].[Description]
```

The reasoning is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909933/861716), which boils down to: `LastSale` is the dominant ordering field as it, sort of, overrides the first `OrderBy`.

All EF queries only have `ORDER BY LastSale`.

I must say agree with EF's implementation. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65910223/861716) explains, the result of two consecutive orderings depends on the sorting algorithm. Which means that all we can say for sure is that the results from *any* LINQ query will be ordered by `LastSale` and the ordering within `LastSale` groups isn't certain. Then, IMO, it's a better choice for SQL translation to handle a second `OrderBy` statement as a full override of the first one so it's visible that no expectations can be based on the first statement. To me it's more intuitive.

The message is: be explicit when ordering by multiple fields. Use `OrderBy - ThenBy`. Don't rely on a database provider's handling of consecutive `OrderBy` statements.

Comment: I too agree with EF's implementation, due to the nature of deferred execution.  I see that if I change to a custom typed datacontext, using EF6, in LinqPad, I see the expected behavior.  Thanks for helping me understand!

Answer (score 3):

This is all in terms of local data, but EF wants to do the logical equivalent when building the expression tree and writing your query.

You should research the concept of [stable sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important). When you use a stable sorting algorithm, the original order of equal items is preserved.

So let's say you have data like this with obvious first name/last name fields:

```
Brad Jones
Tom Smith
Sam Jones
Jim Doe
James Smith
Ryan Smith
```

If you order initially by only by first name, you get this:

```
Brad Jones
James Smith
Jim Doe
Ryan Smith
Sam Jones
Tom Smith
```

If you now take this sorted list, and again sort by last name, you get a result sorted by both fields, where later sorts have precedence over earlier sorts... but you ***only guarantee the exact order if the sort is stable***:

```
Jim Doe
Brad Jones
Sam Jones
James Smith
Ryan Smith
Tom Smith
```

This brings us to the question of what algorithm .Net uses, and whether it's stable. [To the documentation we go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__), where we find this in the Remarks section:

> This method performs a stable sort

The specific algorithm is *not documented* here. I believe it's a [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but leaving that out of the documentation is probably intentional, to allow the maintainers to update for the best available option that meets the stability requirement should something better be discovered.

But, again, that's for local data. Databases will do what the SQL tells them.

Comment: The docs also state: _"Because IOrderedEnumerable<TElement> inherits from IEnumerable<T>, you can call OrderBy or OrderByDescending on the results of a call to OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy or ThenByDescending. **Doing this introduces a new primary ordering that ignores the previously established ordering**."_ The "stable" property indeed preserves the order of equal items in the second sort, so the result looking like the sort is inverted in regards to OrderBy calls is dependent on the contents of the data being sorted.

Comment: @CodeCaster That statement is misleading. In my examples, after the first sort Brad Jones comes before Jim Doe. I believe what they're trying to say is calling OrderBy() a second time can override that, which we see in the second example, where Brad Jones comes after. It ignores the order in that it pays no special attention, but because the order is there in the IOrderedEnumerable, you get predictable results. And if this were linq to entities, you might have a point about using `.ThenBy()`. But for EF, this will be translated to SQL and do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is quite simple and it makes total sense:

The first part of the query

```cs
context.Entities.Where(x => x.ForeignKeyId == id)
```

would be translated to SQL more or less like this

```sql
select * from Entities
```

Adding the first order by

```cs
.OrderBy(x => x.FirstSortField)
```

it would be translated to this

```sql
select * from (
   select * from Entities
)
order by FirstSortField
```

and then adding the second order by

```cs
.OrderBy(x => x.FirstSortField)
.OrderBy(x => x.SecondSortField)
```

would be translated to:

```sql
select * from (
   select * from (
      select * from Entities
   )
   order by FirstSortField
)
order by SecondSortField
```

Entity framework is smart enough to simplify to something like

```sql
select * from Entities
order by SecondSortField, FirstSortField
```

Comment: A bit too smart, as semantically only `order by SecondSortField` should remain. The subquery is fundamentally unordered without a `TOP`

Comment: No, Entity framework is smart enough to just ditch the first `OrderBy`. Please check things like this before posting.

Comment: @GertArnold, you should check yourself. EF used to "override" the orderbys, but currently it composes it. Try it yourself and see with your eyes if you don't believe.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm crazy, but I see two chained OrderBy's translated into one `ORDER BY` in SQL. Both with EF6 (which the question is about) and EF core 3.

Comment: @GertArnold are you sure (you are using different properties each order by :D? I have LinqPad open with EF6 and it translates both order bys in .Net Core 3, 3.1, and 5.0.

Comment: Yep. The only difference I can think of is the database provider. Mine is Sql Server. The query is a simple DbSet + Where + 2 OrderBy's.

Comment: That could be the difference, I used LINQPad DemoDB.sdf with SQL CE 4.0 Provider

Comment: Looks like you're using LINQ-to-SQL then, which is the default Linqpad (5) data provider.