# Is there a reason why I should reverse these lines of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm doing some practice on Dataquest.

Here's the exercise:

Create a function, sort, that:

- Takes as input a list of lists.
- Orders the outer list by the third element in the inner lists in descending order.
- Resolves ties by sorting by the first one in ascending order.
- Modifies the input in place..

What I've done:

```
def sort_index(some_list):
    some_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    some_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

The output:

- Function sort_index did not correctly modify the value of argument number 1.

Can someone explain to me why it worked when I reversed lines 1 and 2:

```
def sort_index(some_list):
    some_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    some_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
```

Comment: If you change the order of the sorts, that changes the output

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's obvious, the question is why the second order produces the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

The first .sort call is not needed, only the second one (with `x[2]`) matters if there are no ties. The only remaining behavior to understand is what happens to ties.

The list .sort method in Python is a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important), that's needed for it to work.

For example, if your input contains `('a', None, 5)` and `('b', None, 5)` tied on `x[2]`, then the first .sort call will put them in this order (relative to each other) because `'a' < 'b'`, and the second .sort call will keep this order, because `5 == 5` and the sort is stable.