# Move filtered row to head of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 with two columns: CODE & RANK

```
     CODE RANK
100  12   1
212  6    2
358  4    3
342  10   4
111  8    5
```

My dataframe is ordered by Rank. I don't want to change completely the sorting rule but want to move to head some rows generated by a filter:

```
  df1[df1['RANK'] >= 4]]
```

The result should then be:

```
     CODE RANK
342  10   4
111  8    5
100  12   1
212  6    2
358  4    3
```

Do you know how I can do it properly?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df1[df1['RANK'] >= 4], df1[df1['RANK'] < 4]])
```

Output:

```py
CODE    RANK
10      4
8       5
12      1
6       2
4       3
```

Or faster way as suggested by @mozway:

```py
m = df1['RANK'] >= 4
df2 = pd.concat([df1[m], df1[~m]])
```

Comment: Note that `≥4` and `<4` are mutually exclusive and complementary (except for NaNs), so you can compute only one mask `m = df1['RANK'] >= 4` then `pd.concat([df1[m], df1[~m]])` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with a custom key and stable sorting:

```
df.sort_values(by='RANK', key=lambda s: s.lt(4), kind='stable')

# or
# df.sort_values(by='RANK', key=lambda s: s.ge(4), ascending=False, kind='stable')
```

Output:

```
     CODE  RANK
342    10     4
111     8     5
100    12     1
212     6     2
358     4     3
```

How it works:
when passing the key, a boolean Series is created with `True`/`False` values. `True` is seen as `1` and is sorted **after** `False` (equivalent to `0`).

```
df['RANK'].lt(4)
100     True      # sorted after False
212     True
358     True
342    False
111    False
Name: RANK, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `key` and `kind` parameters, because default sorting algo is `quicksort`, see also [what is stability in sorting algorithms and why is it important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('RANK', key=lambda x: x >= 4, ascending=False, kind='stable')
#alternative solution
#df1 = df.sort_values('RANK', key=lambda x: x < 4, kind='stable')
print (df1)
     CODE  RANK
342    10     4
111     8     5
100    12     1
212     6     2
358     4     3
```