# Does the qsort() function provide performance guarantees?

Tags: c, standards

Does the C standard require the standard-library `qsort()` function provide a specific level of performance?  The name suggests the use of an O(n log n) algorithm such as [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).  Could a standards-conforming library implement it using the O(n^2) [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), or even the O(n!) [bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort)?

Comment: No, it does not specify the sorting method or performance.

Comment: The TL;DR: _No_ `qsort` (i.e. `quicksort`) can be O(n log n) but, worst case, it can be O(n^2). `mergesort` is _always_ O(n log n) time with O(n) [extra] space. Note that `qsort` on some systems uses insertion sort on the lower levels (based on a heuristic). So, the answer is "it depends"

Comment: Look at the `qsort()` source code. It is a blend of sorting methods optimized to avoid the worst-case scenarios inherent in quicksort. You can't do much better.

Comment: I don't think it specifies an upper limit on the extra space it uses either. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The specification is very simple. It says nothing about complexity, either memory or time.

Comment: Similarly, the name `bsearch()` suggests that it will do a binary search, and the specification of the comparison function allows for this, but there's no actual requirement that it do so.

Comment: The implementation is free to generate whatever code it likes, so long as the output satisfies the requirements of the C Standard. Of course, a compiler will use the best methods at its disposal, because it wants good rep.

Comment: This is what people in the standardization community call a "quality of implementation" issue. There's little need to legislate this in the spec, the marketplace will weed out bad designs. Furthermore, sorting is well understood technology, there's no excuse for a library to use a bad algorithm.

Comment: In practice, very commonly this is based on [Engineering a sort function, Bentley 1993](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/spe.4380231105).

Comment: Rather than "performance" you may wish to use terms like "runtime complexity" or "space complexity" to more precisely discuss what aspects of scalability you're concerned with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C89, C99, C11, and C17 standards, no particular big-O behavior is required.

This is the language from the C89 standard, under heading 7.10.5.2. The other standards contain identical language.

> ## Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
> int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
> ```
>
> ## Description
>
> The qsort function sorts an array of nmemb objects, the initial element of which is pointed to by base. The size of each object is specified by size.
>
> The contents of the array are sorted into ascending order according to a comparison function pointed to by compar, which is called with two arguments that point to the objects being compared. The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>
> If two elements compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is unspecified.
>
> ## Returns
>
> The qsort function returns no value.

The standard does not specify a particular algorithm or particular speed. In fact, it goes out of its way to allow more sorting algorithms by not requiring a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important). I interpret this to mean that Bogosort is a standards-compliant way to implement qsort.