# List.Sort(by length) returns different results on different computers

Tags: c#, sorting

I have the following code :

```
List<string> Words = item.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
Words.Sort((a, b) => b.Length.CompareTo(a.Length));
```

Which is supposed to sort a List of words from a line in a file (item) according to their size. However, if two words have the same length, they are supposed to be sorted by the order of appearence in the line.

The problem here is that if the line is, for example "a b c", on my computer, the list will have three sorted items (0 - a, 1 - b, 2 - c), but on another computer, using the same .Net version (4.5), the sorted items will be (0 - c, 1 - b, 2 - a)

Is there a way to enforce the same result troughout different computers ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the exact same CLR version on both machines? What is the value of `Environment.Version`?

Comment: It is the same, Environment.Version returns 4.0.30319.18408

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force the same results using LINQ and set of `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` calls, instead of `Sort`.

```
var result = source.Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
                   .OrderBy(x => x.v.Length)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.i)
                   .Select(x => x.v)
                   .ToList();
```

But you should be aware, that it will create new list, instead of sorting existing one in place:

Comment: [OrderBy is already stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209935/orderby-and-orderbydescending-are-stable), at least for LINQ to Objects; the Index/ThenBy do not affect the result.

Answer (score 11):

[`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) is an [unstable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), meaning in your case that elements of the same length can go in different order.

> This implementation performs an unstable sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the order of elements that are equal.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @david.pfx "_This does not answer the question_" `List<string> Words = item.Split(' ').OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToList();` 
Crediteds to go to **user2864740** and **MarcinJuraszek**, I didn't feel good to put it to my answer :).

Comment: You should ensure that your answer is as good as you can make it. If you use work by others, give them credit but it is the quality of the final answer that will matter to other readers. Feel free to edit your answer at any time to improve it.

Comment: Thanks AlexD, but it has the same problem.

Comment: @adre76 `OrderBy` performs stable sort, the code from the comment above is expected to work. Could you tell me which input string causes the problem?

Comment: @AlexD If I want to get the longest string, I would have to output the last element on the List, which would not work on every case. I should have clarified, it works, but not for what I require. The output will always be the same, but it will be inverted, and therefore, not what i require

Comment: @adre76 Ahh, but then just use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`. It should make the trick :).

Comment: @AlexD Oh... should have thought of that. Yes, it works. Thanks for the time you put into it.

Answer (score 1):

The method List.Sort() is an unstable sort. You cannot predict the order of duplicate keys.

There are 2 generic methods to solve this problem: use a stable sort, or force uniqueness by extending the key to include identity information.

One of the common stable sorts is an Insertion sort. I believe this would be the sort used by SortedList, but it does not allow duplicate keys. Failing that, you can write your own, either in Linq or by hand. Even a bubble sort is stable!

The preferred way is to keep the item identity. Create a list of pairs, where each pair consists of the key value and its position in the list. Sort the list of pairs, or insert the pairs directly into a sorted list, because every pair is unique. The ordering of these pairs, and the keys they contain, is guaranteed the same on all platforms.